# Applescript using if then statements and choose from list

Tags: applescript

I'm working on a course selection script and each person should only be able to select three courses. I am having issues figuring out how to repeat choose from list if the user selects less than or more than three courses, and only proceed if three choices are selected. Converting the choices from the list to string should work however nothing happens after choosing from list

```
set theClassList to {"Math ", "English ", "Science ", "I&S ", "Design "}

repeat

set theClass to choose from list theClassList with prompt "Select three courses" with multiple selections allowed

set theClassString to theClass as string

if words in theClassString ≠ 3 then

    display dialog "Please select three courses"
    exit repeat

else if words in theClassString = 3 then
    display dialog "Ok"

end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a clever idea to count the words in the `theClassString` (which would be done using `number of words in theClassString`, instead of simply `words in theClassString`).  This would work the majority of the time, until a user includes `"I&S"` as one of their options, which sadly counts as two words, `"I"` and `"S"`, since the ampersand is not a word character.

You also had your `exit repeat` in the wrong half of the `if...then...else` block, since you want to break the loop when the user selects 3 courses, not when they fail to select 3 courses.

Rather than attempting to coerce the result of the list selection into a string, you ought to just count the number of items in the result, which can be done in one of three ways:

1. `count theClass`
2. `length of theClass`
3. `number in theClass`

Here's a reworked version of your script:

```
property theClassList : {"Math ", "English ", "Science ", "I&S ", "Design "}
property text item delimiters : linefeed

set choices to missing value

repeat
    if choices ≠ missing value then display dialog ¬
        "You must select precisely three courses"

    set choices to choose from list theClassList with prompt ¬
        "Select three courses" with multiple selections allowed

    if choices = false or the number of choices = 3 then exit repeat
end repeat

if choices = false then return
display dialog choices as text
```

---

...And here's a version that uses a recursive handler instead of a repeat loop:

```
property theClassList : {"Math", "English", "Science", "I&S", "Design"}
property text item delimiters : linefeed

to choose()
    tell (choose from list theClassList ¬
        with prompt ("Select three courses") ¬
        with multiple selections allowed) to ¬
        if it = false or its length = 3 then ¬
            return it

    display dialog "You must select precisely three courses"
    choose()
end choose

display alert (choose() as text)
```

Comment: Just added a second version of the script that uses a recursive handler instead of a repeat loop.  No reason why, just kinda felt like it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help on this issue, however, I am confused about what the missing value means for this script, as replacing the missing value with 3 seems to also work. Thanks again

Comment: What made you replace it with `3` ?  If you replaced both occurrences of `missing value` with 3, then, yes, it wouldn't affect how the script functions.  You can actually replace those occurrences with any unary value and the script will still operate in an identical fashion.  It's actually only there for one reason: so the dialog saying `"You must select precisely three courses"` doesn't get shown on the initial entry into the repeat loop.  Once the loop is entered and a choice is made, that variable won't ever again equal `missing value` (or any unary value), so the dialog will instantiate.

Comment: As for the choice of `missing value`, it's standard practice for variables that need to be initialised but don't require a specific value to be assigned a "non-value".  In AppleScript, this is represented by `missing value` (or by `null`); in other languages, it's often implicit simply by declaring a variable but not assigning a value.  It lets the reader know that the variable is not currently being used, but will be used later.

Comment: This made much more sense to me. Thanks a lot for the speedy replies

Answer (score 0):

to make it easier by respecting the fluidity of your script. It would be better to declare your "theClass" as a rather string list and declare n as count of list. Below is your modified script or the following that takes your own but declaring n to count of words in "theClassString".`

```
set theClassList to {"Math", "English", "Science", "I & S", "Design"}

repeat

set theClass to choose from list theClassList with prompt "Select three courses" with multiple selections allowed

set theClassString to theClass as list

set n to count of theClassString

set n to do shell script "echo" & n

if n ≠ "3" then

display dialog "Please select three courses"
exit repeat

else if n = "3" then
display dialog "Ok"

end if
end repeat
```

***Below
By declaring String***

```
set theClassList to {"Math ", "English ", "Science ", "I&S ", "Design "}

repeat

    set theClass to choose from list theClassList with prompt "Select three courses" with multiple selections allowed

    set theClassString to theClass as string

    set n to count of words in theClassString

    set n to do shell script "echo " & n

    if n ≠ "3" then

        display dialog "Please select three courses"
        exit repeat

    else if n = "3" then
        display dialog "Ok"

    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

um maybe like this

```
set theClassList to {"Math ", "English ", "Science ", "I&S ", "Design "}

repeat
    
    set theClass to choose from list theClassList with prompt "Select three courses" with multiple selections allowed
    
    set theClassString to theClass as string
    
    set n to count of words in theClassString
    
    set n to do shell script "echo " & n
    
    if n ≠ "3" then
        
        display dialog "Please select three courses" buttons {"ok"}
        
        
    else if n = "3" then
        display dialog "Ok"
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```